# Adding textboxes or other ways

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im currently making a recipe search app. I am including a feature where in users can narrow their search down by adding which recipes should contain certain ingredients that i may or may not have.

I've seen alot of examples online, the best one ive seen so far is utilized by supercook.com

although that requires jquery(no doubt) i have yet to know jquery so textboxes would be fine, but the problem is users have different numbers of ingredients, i will add default of 5 textboxes, if a user has 7, he/she should just click an add function wherein it will automatically add 2 more textboxes. This may or may not require jquery, i am keen on learning it though... i need suggestions and help on whats the simplest/best way to do this.

Comment: please paste some html and jquery code you have done so far.

Comment: Currently on a break, in a couple hours or so. stay tuned i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the below code which will add text boxes. If you need this only then it may help you.

html code

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="addTextBox">
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" /><br />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="hidText" id="hidText" />
</form>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-decoration: none;" id="add_more_txtbox">Add More</a>
```

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript"    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#add_more_txtbox").click(function(){
        var hidden_value=parseInt($("#hidText").val())+1;
        $("#hidText").val(hidden_value);
        var add_str='<input type="text" name="text'+hidden_value+'" id="text'+hidden_value+'" /><br />';
        $("#addTextBox").append(add_str);
    });
});
</script>
```

please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Is there any alternative to this using jquery? 

Also, may i ask, whats more of significance today, jquery or javascript. I know the basics of javascript so i find it more pleasing to use although when i tried to make a interactive slideshow, jquery was the better man.

Comment: obviously jquery is more significant that javascript.but you can use javascript but then you need to write more code than now.